# Avoiding oscillating moving in layout algorithm

Tags: javascript, algorithm, layout, geometry

Following on from this question here:

[Calculate distance to move a box to remove intersection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24209237/calculate-distance-to-move-a-box-to-remove-intersection)

I have a problem where moving one box causes it to overlap with another box, and the algorithm as it currently stands will just move the first box back in (almost) the direction it came from causing it to overlap the first box again and so forth. Is there a good way to avoid this situation? I feel like remembering the vector from last time and somehow combining it with the new proposed move might be the solution.

Here's a simple fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/x8MT3/4/

Notice how the one box is moved, but then overlaps the other box, so the box is moved again back in the opposite direction and after 6 cycles, is still overlapping.

Here's the code for the add method - it adds boxes to a list, checking the current members for otherlaps:

```
    self.add = function (item, iteration) {
        // check intersections with existing boxes
        iteration = iteration || 0;
        if (iteration < 6) {
            for (var i = 0; i < boxes.length; i++) {
                var stationary = boxes[i];
                var boundsA = getBounds(item);
                var boundsB = getBounds(stationary);
                if (doesIntersect(boundsA, boundsB)) {
                    item.elem.addClass("overlapped");
                    // move item
                    // Find vector from mid point of one box to the other
                    var centerA = {
                        x: item.x + item.width / 2,
                        y: item.y + item.height / 2
                    };
                    var centerB = {
                        x: stationary.x + stationary.width / 2,
                        y: stationary.y + stationary.height / 2
                    };
                    var line = {
                        x1: centerA.x,
                        y1: centerA.y,
                        x2: centerB.x,
                        y2: centerB.y
                    }
                    var vector = {
                        x: Math.min(item.x + item.width, stationary.x + stationary.width) - Math.max(item.x, stationary.x),
                        y: Math.min(item.y + item.height, stationary.y + stationary.height) - Math.max(item.y, stationary.y)
                    };
                    var signX = line.x1 - line.x2 > 0 ? 1 : -1;
                    var signY = line.y1 - line.y2 > 0 ? 1 : -1;
                    item.x = item.x + vector.x * signX;
                    item.y = item.y + vector.y * signY;
                    item.elem.offset({
                        left: item.x,
                        top: item.y
                    });     
                    return self.add(item, iteration + 1);
                }
            }
        }
        boxes.push(item);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Why do not you use iterative process ... ???

- as I see it you want to rearrange boxes so they not overlap
- but do not change the layout too much
- if you do not mind some space between boxes (the will not touch) then:

[image: box rearrange]

Algorithm:

1.find overlapped box

- red box

2.find movement direction

- green vector
- between box centers
- then change it size to movement step (few pixels...)

3.compute new position of overlapped

- then check for new overlaps
- if too close to another box stop movement in that direction
- Blue arrows shows collision stop

4.apply this (loop from bullet 1) for all overlapped boxes

- do just one or few steps
- not the whole movement !!!

5.iteratively loop all (from bullet 1)

- stop when no overlapped box found
- or process has timeout-ed ...
- because this can get also stuck

[Notes]

- if box centers are the same
- then add random direction to movement vector
- the whole process can be applied more times with decreasing step for more speed